# How do I get the pr2_gazebo_doors_demo to work?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I tried to run the demo exactly as descibed in the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/PR2OpenDoor).

I get the following error:

roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_generator].
Please check all  'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.

What can I do to get it working?

I have ubuntu 10.4 and diamondback pr2all installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10949/how-do-i-get-the-pr2_gazebo_doors_demo-to-work?/) by [Andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/968/andy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated the [door wiki for diamondback](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/PR2OpenDoor).

But there appears to be a problem with redundant nodes as Andy suggested.  The fix have been pushed into trunk, pending next release.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on 2011-09-27**:
it is useful.this solution helps me a lot .

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-25**:
Thanks for the updates.  Changes committed into pr2_doors trunk.

**Comment by [Andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/968/andy/) on 2011-08-19**:
Ok, i got it working by removing two node definitions. 1) pr2_doors_actions/launch/door_actions.xml: remove/comment lines 56 to 64. 2) pr2_doors_executive/doors.launch: remove/comment lines 15 to 20.

**Comment by [Andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/968/andy/) on 2011-08-18**:
the name conflict seems to come from

**Comment by [Andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/968/andy/) on 2011-08-18**:
I removed the "experimental" SVN checkouts (which were required for cturtle) and went through all steps in the wiki, but the problem persists...